# How to model a "repeating timeout" in Reactive?

Tags: c#, reactive

I have an observable stream that sends out events:

```
---*--*--*---*------------------------*---*---***--**-----
```

I want wrap this stream into another one that will add "please hold" events every N seconds if there hasn't been an event in the last N seconds:

Desired result:  (X's are newly injected events

```
---*--*--*---*---X---X---X---X---X---X*---*---***--**---X-
```

I'm trying to model it in an idiomatic reactive way, but haven't found an operator that will let me do this easily. Timeout is the one that seems to come closes, except that it doesn't repeat, and it actually terminates the stream.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly "hacked" solution. It is not clear what the code is doing.

```
public static IObservable<T> RepeatingTimeout<T>(ITestableObservable<T> events, TimeSpan timespan, T timeoutEvent, TestScheduler scheduler)
{
    var groups = events
        .GroupByUntil(x => 1, g => g, g => g.Throttle(timespan, scheduler)) // group events into observables so that each observable contains sequence of events where each event is sooner than timespan
        .Select(x => 
            x.Concat(Observable.Interval(timespan, scheduler).Select(_ => timeoutEvent) // concatenate timeout events at intervals after each group of events
            .StartWith(timeoutEvent))
            )
        .Switch(); // return events from latest observable
    return groups;
}
```

And this is test that shows that it works:

```
[Test]
public void RepeatedTimeout()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    var events = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
        OnNext(4, 1),
        OnNext(7, 2),
        OnNext(10, 3),
        OnNext(14, 4),
        OnNext(30, 5),
        OnNext(35, 6),
        OnCompleted<int>(36)
        );

    var timespan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(5);
    var timeoutEvent = -1;

    var groups = RepeatingTimeout(events, timespan, timeoutEvent, scheduler);

    groups.Do(x => Console.WriteLine("G " + scheduler.Clock + " " + x));


    var results = scheduler.Start(() => groups, 0, 0, 100);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help.   This test doesn't print anything for me though?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this problem later, this is the solution I ended up with:

```
 public static class ObservableExtensions
 {
    public static IObservable<T> PulseDuringInactivity<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan pulseInterval, IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        return source
            //for each incoming event, we create a new observable stream, that contains this event being repeated infinitely many times over at our pulse interval
            //these repeating values will serve as the pulse
            .Select(sourceValue => RepeatingObservable(sourceValue, pulseInterval, scheduler))

            //However obviously that creates way too many events.  What we we'll do is throw away all of these repeating observables, as soon as there's a single event coming in on any of our streams.
            //this is what .Switch() does, and it immediately unsubscribes from the now-irrelevant streams, which can then be gc'd.  For more information about the workings of this technique,
            //check out the tests in ObservableExtensionTests.cs
            .Switch();
    }

    static IObservable<T> RepeatingObservable<T>(T valueToRepeat, TimeSpan repeatInterval, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Interval(repeatInterval, scheduler ?? Scheduler.Default).Select(_ => valueToRepeat);
    }
}
```